# Запрос двух переменных с базы данных(Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: android, firebase, realtime

```
    static double lat2;

    static double lon2;

    private void InitMapElements() {

    DatabaseReference zonesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("markers");

    DatabaseReference zone1Ref = zonesRef.child("m-1"); // путь в базе данных
    DatabaseReference zone1NameRef = zone1Ref.child("latit");

    DatabaseReference zone2NameRef = zone1Ref.child("longit");

        zone1NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { // чтение первой координаты

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Double lat1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
                lat2 = lat1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
            }
        });
        zone2NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { //чтение второй координаты
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Double lon1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
                lon2 = lon1;

            }

           @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
}
```

Не получается получать две переменные в режиме онлайн с последующем сохранением в статическую переменную из Firebase Realtime Database,переменные получают значение только один раз при вызове метода. С одной переменной работает всё нормально переменная меняется если изменить значение на базе,но с двумя не работает.

Comment: [Пример получение одной переменной](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpFDFK44pX8)